# php shell_exec no permission

Tags: php, bash

I am using a php script to call a backend python script.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(-1);
   $output = shell_exec("sh run.sh 2>&1");
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The run.sh script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget http://markets.usatoday.com/custom/usatoday-com/html-mktscreener.asp
python hw7-9.py index.html
echo "done";
```

The output is

```
run.sh: wget: not found
run.sh: python: not found
done
```

If I run it normally from shell it works perfectly.
to try and fix the not found I did "which wget" and replace full path

```
/afs/cad/sw.common/bin/wget -O index.html http://markets.usatoday.com/custom/usatoday-com/html-mktscreener.asp
```

I get permission denied

Comment: Check that your web server has write permissions to the folder.

Comment: define the fullpath to output file too...

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions of your php and your shell script?

I've used the same approach that you're using, successfully. Full ownership and attribute details below.

```
# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2332 Jan  4 23:07 daily.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  232 Oct 30 22:43 get_stuff.sh
```

The user/group ownership on your system will vary. The read/write/execute permissions don't have to strictly match mine, either. But for reference, my setup is achieved via:

```
chmod 644 daily.php
chmod 755 get_stuff.sh
chown root:root *
```